# Using scanf with char arrays and their size

Tags: c, overflow, constants, scanf

I am learning C with Deitel's and Deitel's C programming book. Most of the times, when they use the scanf fucntion, for a `char name[20];`, they usually write: `scanf("%19s", name);`, in order to avoid buffer overflow.

But what can we do if the length of the array is a symbolic constant, say `#define LENGTH 20`. Obviously, using `scanf("%LENGTHs, name);` or even `scanf("%"LENGTH"s", name);` doesn't really help.

My problem also applies to the fscanf function, when we have to do with a stream different than `stdin`.

Comment: Use `fgets()` and avoid using `scanf()`.  `scanf()` does input and parsing and is inadequate for both tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

#define LENGTH 20

int main(void){
    char name[LENGTH+1];

    scanf("%" STR(LENGTH) "s", name);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

See [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) for more information on this.

Answer (score 3):

Is better to use `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)`

But If you want to use scanf() you can create the format at runtime or 
*re-define LENGTH to be a string;*

```
#define LENGTH "20"
scanf(" %" LENGTH "[^\n]", name);
```

Edit:

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH "10"

int main(void) {
    char name[20];
    scanf(" %" LENGTH "[^\n]", name);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:** *abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz* 
**Output:** *abcdefghij*

All the best.

Comment: The size of the array and `LENGTH`  are not related. So `scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);` is better than `scanf(" %" LENGTH "[^\n]", name);` in this case.